# TypeError: cpu_count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to get a hold of the multiprocessing (2 CPUs on my Mac). My code is roughly the following:

```
def new_func(i):
    Rewards, Times, CummulativeRewards, Weights = Q_learning(model, variants = 2, stages = 3, gamma = 0.975, epsilon = 0.99, batchSize = i, buffer = 3000, randSeed = 42, replay = None)
    return CummulativeRewards

from joblib import Parallel, delayed import multiprocessing

BatchSize = [100, 300]
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count(2)
Rewards, Times, CuRew, Weights = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(new_func)(i) for i in BatchSize)
```

I get the following error:
`num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count(2)
TypeError: cpu_count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Any ideas what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cpu_count does not take any arguments.  The one positional argument is the self instance `multiprocessing`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count

```
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```